# Is my plan for connecting a generator interlock to a subpanel ok?

Tags: electrical

My son installed a sub pan next to his main panel he installed a generator with an interlock system he did not have enough room in main panel so he removed two 30 amp breakers to the sub panel he installed a 60 amp breaker in main panel to power sub panel and a 30 amp breaker in main panel for the generator.  He ran two 6 Ga hot wires from 60 amp breaker to sub panel a 6 Ga from neutral bar in main panel to neutral bar in sub panel and a 6 Ga ground from main panel ground bar to sub panel ground bar.  (when he moved the two 30 amp breakers to sub panel he ran the hot wires to the breakers but left the ground wires connected to the main panel) which I guess is ok since there are no neutral wires involved. There are only the two 30 amp breakers in the sub panel

Comment: Neutral and ground need to go to the same panel or subpanel as the hots. **Pictures of the panels would help a LOT**.

Comment: Not quite sure how the interlock is accomplished , there should be 4 wires going to the sub unless the cases of both panels are connected with listed metallic fittings. 
The sub has to have the neutrals isolated, I might be more concerned on the feed to the main panel and how the generator is grounded.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the panels involved please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake when he moved the two 30 amp breakers to the sub panel with the two hot wires he left the ground wires connected to the main panel with I guess  is OK  since there are no neutral wires involved